# private method `new' called for MyReminderMailer:Class

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

In a controller, i have:

```
mailer = MyReminderMailer.new
```

the mailer looks like this:

```
class MyReminderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def change_email
    mail(
      from:     default_from,
      to:       default_to,
      subject: "..."
    )
  end

  def default_from
    return '...'
  end

  def default_to
    return '...'
  end
end
```

but got error: private method `new' called for MyReminderMailer:Class

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ActionMailer::Base` has a rather goofy and unintuitive API. Much like controllers, you never explicitly create instances of your mailers. Instead, you interact with them as classes. `new` is marked private in `ActionMailer::Base`, and method calls on the class are subsequently routed through `method_missing` to a new instance of itself. Like I said, unintuitive.

Have a look at the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) for more information on the correct usage of ActionMailer.

Comment: "goofy and unintuitive" is being charitable, I'd probably use strong language :)

Answer (score 6):

Ruby does not allow to call private method in normal way.
You can call it with send method

```
SomeClass.send :method_name

#in your case
MyReminderMailer.send :new
```

And you don't need ActionMailer object.
To send mail just use the method as like class method.

```
MyReminderMailer.change_email.deliver
```

Hope this can help you.